# create API credentials for paypal SANDBOX

Tags: api, paypal, sandbox, credentials

Here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/ there is article how to get API credentials for paypal
But when I logged to the for SANDBOX page the view was different
I do not see any "My selling Tools" link :

http://s49.radikal.ru/i125/1408/be/ee6c8d02449f.png

How can I  create API credentials for paypal SANDBOX ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can go to [PayPal's Sandbox Site](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/)

1.> Login with your Sandbox Account's email and password.

Example

Email: `sandboxaccount@paypal.com`

Password: `testaccount14`

[Note: the above credentials won't work. It's just an example]

2.>After you log-in, click on the 'Profile' option under 'My Account' tab

3.>Try to find the link which says 'Request API credentials'

4.>Now click on 'Set up PayPal API credentials and permissions' under 'Option 1 - PayPal API'

5.>Now click on 'View API Signature' under 'Option 2'

And that should show you the API Credentials(API Username, Password, Signature) for that account

Hope it helps.

NOTE:

PayPal Developer and PayPal Sandbox are two different sites.

[PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/) - allows you to sign-in to the developer's account, which lets you create PayPal sandbox accounts of different types. It also shows you the API credentials for the Sandbox accounts created within it. And also allows you to internally login to PayPal Sandbox account.

[PayPal Sandbox](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com) - allows you to directly sign-in to the sandbox site for a particular sandbox account, using the Sandbox Email and Password that you set while creating the sandbox account(from developers site)

Comment: Try to find the link which says 'Request API credentials' . Good luck

Answer (score 7):

Actually, it's a little easier than going through the account.  You can get them from within your developer account.

Just go to http://developer.paypal.com and login there.  Then go to Applications, Sandbox Accounts, which is where you would have created the sandbox accounts to begin with.

Here you'll see a list of your sandbox accounts with a little drop-down arrow next to them.  Click this to see some extra links:  Profile | Notifications

Click Profile, and then you'll see a tab for API Credentials.

An even quicker way is to just [use this tool](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run).  Login to that with your sandbox account and it will return the API credentials for that account.

Comment: I did this, but in my case there is no "API Credentials" tab.
http://s017.radikal.ru/i440/1408/d1/c585115ddb37.png
Have I to create someway ?

Comment: Did you create a seller account or a buyer account?  Maybe your sandbox account is setup as a personal buyer account..?? Did you try the link I provided?  What does it do when you login to it?

Comment: Andrew, thank you for your help!
I created personal account(buyer account).

I found my prior login to paypal and use it for as API credentials.
But when I tried to pay for seelcted goods I got error "This transaction cannot be processed. The amount to be charged is zero.".

It seems that for testing in Sandbox I have to keep several logins, but I stell confusing "who is who" here.
Could you please explain or give ref to some good explanations as for this.

Comment: Also I tried to get new account at 
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_registration-run
and get error:
Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Comment: To test PayPal payments from beginning to end you need a buyer account and a seller account.  You login as the buyer during checkout to pay the seller account, and then you can see the funds on each end as actual users would see it using your application.  In order to get API credentials you have to use a business account, so set one up as a seller account and use that one.  Then you should be ready to go.

Comment: Paypal has the worst interface I have ever seen in 20 years of programming and integration.  Your solution and the above worked, but I still don't really know how to use these API Credentials?  Where do they go?

Comment: It depends on what sort of a solution you're using.  Are you working with an SDK of some sort?  A plugin for a platform like WordPress?  What exactly?

Answer (score 4):

## 2018 Update

Since the question has been asked, the site has been modified. Here is the new path to find your API credentials for paypal SANDBOX:

1) Go to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/

2) Login with the seller sandbox account

3) Click on the `Profile` then click on `Profile and Settings`

4) Click on `My sellings preferences`

5) Click `Update` for `API Access`

6) Click on `Manage API credentials` in the box `NVP/SOAP API integration (Classic)`

7) Click on `Show` to see your credentials